# Unable to reference GraphQLObjectType while creating it

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm trying to dynamically generate a graphql scheme from a json config. But i'm unable to create a GraphQLList to itself.

json:

```
{
  "label": "user",
  "properties": [
    {
      "key": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "key": "id",
      "type": "id"
    },
    {
      "key": "birthday",
      "type": "date"
    },
    {
      "key": "gender",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      key: 'friends',
      type: 'string'
    }
  ]
}
```

The javascript code generating:

```
graphSchemes.forEach(function (graphScheme) {
 graphQLObjects[graphScheme.label] = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: graphScheme.label,
  fields: graphScheme.properties.reduce((fields, property) => {
    if (property.key === 'friends') {
      fields[property.key] = {
        type: new graphql.GraphQLList(graphQLObjects[graphScheme.label])
      };
      return fields;
    }
    fields[property.key] = {
      type: TYPES[property.type]
    };
    return fields;
  }, {})
});
```

});

The issue here is:

```
type: new graphql.GraphQLList(graphQLObjects[graphScheme.label])
```

There is no "graphQLObjects[graphScheme.label]"

How can I go around this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible a field to reference the type itself by putting the fields in a wrapper function.

an example:

```
var routeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageRoute',
  fields: function () {
    return {
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      routes: {
        type: new GraphQLList(routeType),
        resolve: (route) => {
          return route.routes;
        }
      }
    };
  }
});
```